# Using custom google action offline on a smartphone

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I created a [google action](https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant) that is meant to be used on an android smartphone with the google assistant. The action should be used offline because the smartphone will be connected to the wifi generated by a device, and the action will send a HTTP request to that device. Is it possible to do it? Should I follow the standard [procedure](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-enable-Google-Now-offline-voice-recognition-on-my-Android-phone) for using the google assistant offline?

Answer (score 0):

Actions on Google is not available offline. It requires access to the public Internet.

Comment: Is there a workaround to simulate it offline? Just for a prototype

Comment: The work you'd need to put in to make it available offline is non-trivial. At that point it wouldn't make a lot of sense to use Actions on Google.